# What is the alternative for nested for loops in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to know what is the alternative for two nested `for` loops in Scala?

I am converting `C` code to Scala: I am using two `map` operationss instead of two nested `for` loops. Is it correct or are other options available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give some example to see how hard is your problem.

Most times you should use just single `for` loop instead of two nested loops. Consider following snippet:

```
scala> val array = Array.tabulate(2,3)( (a,b) => a+b )
array: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2), Array(1, 2, 3))

scala> var sum : Int = 0
sum: Int = 0

scala> for {
     | a <- array
     | b <- a
     | } {
     | sum += b
     | }

scala> sum
res175: Int = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the alternative for two nested for loops in scala?

Scala for loops are not comparable to C-ish for loops. The alternatives that come closest to C are:

- Scala `while`-loop
- `cfor` optimization from spire project. See the spire github here https://github.com/non/spire/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cfor and usage here: https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2014/learning_spire_cfor.html

Example:

```
cfor(0)(_ < x.size, _ + 1)(i => {
  result(i) = 2.0*x(i) + 3.0
})
```